# List CSS not working on my Wordpress page

Tags: css, wordpress

The page I'm working on is not being formatted properly according to certain CSS declarations. Much of the CSS works (I have a lot of inline stuff to override the main stylesheet). My main problem, which has been infinitely frustrating, is not being able to take the bullets off lists. Here's what I have:

```
                <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                  <li><a href="#deadlines">Upcoming Deadlines</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#presentations">Upload Logo</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#registration">Exhibitor Registration</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#floorplan">Exhbitor Prize Give-Away</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#computers">Marketing Toolkit</a></li>
                </ul>
```

Yet the list still gets bulleted. I've tried making a `list-style-type: none;` class and that didn't work. I tried putting a class at the bottom of the master stylesheet and using the class for the list, still nothing. Also tried `list-style-type: none !important;` Anyone know what might be up? Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you perhaps show us where it's not working. A really good rule of thumb for web development questions is to use a tool like [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or [CodePen](http://codepen.io/) to demonstrate an issue. In your case, by just copying your code I've got [this](http://jsfiddle.net/v233a/), which works fine. This suggests there's something else in your code overriding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using firebug, chrome inspector or safari inspector to see what the hierarchy is? Using these tools you can very quickly figure out why something in CSS is overriding something else. Most of these tools will show the rule you can't figure out all crossed out. Then if you scroll down the list you can see what's interfering with it.

All that being said have you tried

```
list-style: none;
```

on the ul element?

Comment: I've tried using just list-style. When I used Chrome inspector and found the ul, the style that comes up is list-style: none... so weird.

Comment: The style on the UL would be sufficient if it wasn't being overridden by something. You just need to find it out, more info and we could help you.

Comment: you could always (temporarily) add !important to the end and see if that changes anything. It might at least let you know you're targetting the right element.

Comment: I've tried !important -- would it still be possible for something to override it?

Comment: Yes. The Inspector shows you things in order that they are considered. Try scrolling around until you find what's interfering. If you look at the computed style option it very often tells you the line number of the highest-priority item so that could be a clue.

Comment: Thanks--I wasn't looking under computed--I now see it has list-style-type: disk; I'm not sure where this is but I'll look around for it. Thank you! Question--how can this override my css? I thought inline always had the highest priority?

Comment: Does it tell yo a line number? On chrome you can actually open up the selector and see the stack of priorities. This has saved me numerous times. Inline should be king but it's possible that something isn't happening the way you think it is. Impossible to say what. Have you got this online somewhere?